# Xcode from MonoTouch

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios, barcode-scanner

Is there a possibility to call methods in a XCode library from MonoTouch? We would like to use the Bardecode (http://www.bardecode.com/) library in our Apps.

Regards
Paul Sinnema

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to call Xcode libraries from MonoTouch.

First you should see if somebody has already created bindings for the library you want to use, if not, you should have a look at how to bind native libraries in MonoTouch.

Here is the documentation on how to bind native libraries: http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c_types

There are also a lot of samples here: https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings